# Git: How to connect SourceTree to my Git-Enabled-Web-Hosting via SSH?

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, git-push, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using [SourceTree](http://sourcetreeapp.com/) on Windows and I'm already successfully pushing my repository to [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/).

I would like to do the same, but instead of pushing to BitBucket, **I would like to push to my Web Hosting Account instead** (i.e. "1&1 Shared Hosting").

My 1and1 account [provides SSH access](http://faq.1and1.co.uk/web_space__access/ssh/3.html) and has git already installed. I tried to connect to the SSH using [PuTTY](http://sourceforge.net/projects/putty.mirror/) and it works. When I enter "git" I can see all the available git commands.

I would need to know:

1. **How to connect SourceTree to the SSH?** I have a domain, username and password, however I don't see such fields in SourceTree or Pageant, which requires a special file format "`.ppk`".
2. Once connected to the SSH, **How to create the repository remotely on my 1&1 account?**
3. Once the repository exists on my hosting, **How to add it as a Remote Repository so I can push to it?**

---

Note: *This question is about the SourceTree-Windows software, which is itself a graphic user interface for most git functions – please don't reply with command line instructions.*

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 11):

The syntax that you have to use in the "Source / URL" field is the following :

```
ssh://<user>@<server_name>/<git_repository_path>
```

For example :

```
ssh://peter@git.mydomain.com/opt/git/project.git
```

(if the repository does not exist yet on the remote server, then you can create an empty one with the following commands :)

```
$ mkdir -p /opt/git/project.git
$ cd /opt/git/project.git
$ git init --bare
```

Comment: is this hosted via some kind of nginx proxy, or why not the scp colon format, e.g. `ssh://peter@mydomain.com:/opt/git/project.git` ?  This is what im facing currently, if i have to use the former, then how when no dedicated server.  This is just ssh. How would the forward slash after domain be mapped, and by what otherwise?

Comment: Well, this is the way it's defined in the docs : [https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols] . You may also use the other SSH syntax : `pete@git.mydomain.com/project.git`

Comment: I see, makes sense then.  Also, i noticed two forward slashes worked, which was the first way i was able to get it to work.  e.g. `blamb@git.mydomain.com//opt/git/project.git`  So wrapping ones head around the fact that whatever goes after the last tld forward slash, is what the server sees from root path, even for a standard ssh user.  That's the part i hadn't grasped yet.  Didnt think it would serve from root like that.

Answer (score 1):

1. The SourceTree documentation has an [article](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=282173660) on that
2. As you know repositories are not created remotely. You have to login to your server and create repository there using your server git commands
3. Select your repo in SourceTree. In the main menu Repository>Repository Settings. There you can add remote repository. The default one is usually named 'origin'

Comment: Thanks but your answer is really unhelpful. #1 the article doesn't say how to connect to SSH, it says to use ssh-keygen but I don't need to generate a key as I already have credentials from my web hosting provider: **the question is where to put them?** Please see the [comment left on the article you linked](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=282173660&focusedCommentId=385914410#comment-385914410). Regarding #2 I didn't know that repositories couldn't be created remotely: You say that I need to login to my server (how?), isn't SourceTree able to login to my server?

Comment: You have to understand more about Git. SourceTree is just a client for it. You said you can type `git` on the server - that means git is installed there. Now it is a matter of setting it up as a server (http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) and then using git to create your repositories using `git init --bare` command. Here is very good source for all your git questions: http://git-scm.com/doc